# SAS Miner - Run Time Error - Error Code: 1012

Tags: sas, runtime-error, regression, enterprise-miner

**SAS Enterprise Miner 14.1**

I run a number of models (20+) as part of a monthly update. I am getting this error code when I try and run a regression model for some of the models, and not for others. This is very confusing as they all use the same data sources. Any ideas?

> ERROR: Run time error was encountered.  The system error returned was 1012.

Comment: Similar issue is being mentioned in http://support.sas.com/kb/41/950.html Quote= *To work around the problem, do not use an apostrophe in your project name.*

Comment: Thanks but I am not using SAS Text Miner. In any case, there are no apostrophes in my project name.

Comment: You need to figure out which model is failing, there may be something specific to that iteration that is causing the issue.

Comment: This is a common problem across multiple (but crucially, not all) models. I am looking at one specifically to determine the cause and this is the error I am getting.